# Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: mismatched tag

Tags: command-line, fonts

I've noticed this error when I try to run some commands from terminal.
For example

```
~ ❯❯❯ emacs --debug-init
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: mismatched tag
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: invalid attribute 'name'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: invalid attribute 'mode'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: invalid attribute 'target'
```

or for

```
~ ❯❯❯ fc-cache -fv
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: mismatched tag
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: invalid attribute 'name'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: invalid attribute 'mode'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/local.conf", line 19: invalid attribute 'target'
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 7 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi: caching, new cache contents: 358 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi: caching, new cache contents: 358 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 116 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 89 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
...
```

This is /etc/fonts/local.con

```
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /etc/fonts/local.conf
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ <?xml version="1.0"?>
   2   │ <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   3   │ <fontconfig>
   4   │   <match target="font">
   5   │     <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
   6   │       <bool>true</bool>
   7   │     </edit>
   8   │     <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
   9   │       <bool>true</bool>
  10   │     <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
  11   │       <const>rgb</const>
  12   │     </edit>
  13   │     <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
  14   │       <const>hintslight</const>
  15   │     </edit>
  16   │     <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
  17   │       <const>lcddefault</const>
  18   │     </edit>
  19   │   </match>
  20   │ </fontconfig>
───────┴────────────────────
```

Any idea where to start?

Comment: Apparently a problem is found at line 19 of the named file. Please, [edit] your question and show the contents of the file. (Or maybe only the first 30 lines if it is very long.)

Comment: There appears to be a missing `</edit>` closing tag after line 9

Comment: Fair enough! It looks you're right! Silly me!